# Error importing scikit-learn in Python environment

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, importerror, data-science

I'm working on a data science project and when I import sklearn, I get the following error:
[image]

I searched on the Internet and tried to solve it by re-installing the library but it didn't work. I also checked the Windows version and current Python installation, both are 64-bit. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating conda  and updated multiple modules like mkl, scipy, sklearn, conda-env etc. using conda instead of pip and it worked.